# Change background tint as per style

Tags: android, android-theme

I am using the MaterialButtons where the colors change as per the background tint. I am changing the styles using setTheme(R.style.theme) in the app but the buttons do not change with the theme. More over if I define the background tint in the style the entire apps background is messed up.

example

```
<style name="AppThemeGreen" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/green</item>
    </style>
```

How do I set the tint color as per the theme I do not want to find the views and use checks progmatically. That would be too tedious how do I do it using styles.

Comment: google for button theme

Answer (score 0):

you can create style like this in style.xml file

```
<style name="PrimaryButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and give it to button as below

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/click_me"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton" />
```